How does burning work in Brotato?
In Brotato, the special effect of Burning is represented by:

#x# (% of elemental damage)

For example, the common Wand deals 3x3 (100% elemental) while the legendary Wand deals 12x9 (100% elemental).
Under the burn special effect on the wiki, it says:

Burning deals x + (100% Elemental) each second, for y seconds.

Does this mean that for the legendary wand I described above, that the x value is the 12 and the y value is the 9? Meaning that the legendary wand's per second burning damage will be 12 + whatever my elemental damage score is and that it will last for 9 seconds. Is that correct?

According to Reddit, OP was asking about 5x10 damage, and it's stated that:

The number means that the fire deals 5 on each tick, and that it ticks 10 times.

So yes, your legendary wand will deal 12 damage each second, for 9 seconds.
This is true unless you have Eyes Surgery:

Eyes Surgery reduces the time between each tick of burning damage by 10%, or 0.1 second for each Eyes Surgery you have. This means that targets with the burn debuff will take damage every 0.9/0.8/0.7 second


To clarify, is 12 the base damage and then it adds the elemental damage modifier? Or is the 12 fixed?

@Pyrotechnical this is also taken from the wiki: "Some elemental weapons also have the ability to set enemies on fire, inflicting the Burn debuff. Which deals damage each second and that damage scales with the elemental damage stat."
